# Compare the kernel density estimates of two histograms

Tags: python

I want to compare model results to the actual data distributionally, e.g., say there is an 80% overlap between the two distributions. I could use earth movers distance on the histograms, but then the bin size would be arbitrary.

I'm using the following code to [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3hrU.png) the two distributions visually using kernel density estimates. Is there a different way that lets me calculate the similarity of the two distributions?

```
sns.distplot(actual,hist = False, kde = True,color='tab:blue', kde_kws = {'shade': True, 'linewidth': 2.5}, label ="Actual")
sns.distplot(model, hist = False, kde = True,color='tab:orange', kde_kws = {'shade': True, 'linewidth': 2.5}, label ="Model")
```

Comment: Have a look at the [Kullback–Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence), it mesures a distance between two distributions.